# Dealing with Typescript Vue component uninitialized reactive object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

In a composition API Vue 3 component, I'm using reactive objects that'll be populated asynchronously with external data.
I'm using "nullable" `{}` object for that purpose:

```js
import { Ref, ref } from 'vue'
import { Car } from '@mytypes/vehicules'

const car: Ref<Car|{}> = ref({})

fetch('/cars/42').then((result: Car) => {
  car.value = result
}
```

So I can show potentially empty data on the template

```html
<h1>{{ car.model }}</h1>
<label>Brand</label> {{ car.brand }}
<label>Engine</label> {{ car.engine }}
<label>Color</label> {{ car.color }}
```

It seems to me like a dirty hack and each time I do that, I'm facing the issue that I need to chain declare `Car|{}` everywhere the value is propagated to keep Typescript happy enough.

I imagine there is a much proper way to do that, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the reference as nullable:

```
const car: Ref<Car | null> = ref(null);
```

And then use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in my template:

```
<h1>{{ car?.model }}</h1>
```